# Django: get_default of Charfield shows empty string

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model field of `CharField`/`TextField`

```
location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Now I check the default value in Django shell

```
[In}: User._meta.get_field('location').get_default()

[Out]: ''
```

I didn't mention any default value then how it's setting to `''`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an empty string if there is no explicit `default` value. From [the source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#CharField):

```
def get_default(self):
    """Return the default value for this field."""
    return self._get_default()

@cached_property
def _get_default(self):
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default
        return lambda: self.default

    if not self.empty_strings_allowed or self.null and not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls:
        return return_None
    return str  # return empty string
```